# Why do I need to declare a variable for one prototype method call, but not for another?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working with this relatively simple code here:

```
Array.prototype.doubleAll = function () {
  output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    output.push(this[i] * 2);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log([1,2,3].doubleAll());

Array.prototype.myEach = function (fun) {
  output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    output.push(fun(this[i]));
  }
  return output;
};

a = [1,2,3];

a.myEach(function (num) {
  console.log(num);
});
```

The first `console.log` command, called directly on an array rather than a variable pointing to an array, works fine; the second `console.log` works on a *variable* pointing to an array, but not directly on an array.

For example,

```
[1,2,3].myEach(...)
```

fails, but

```
[1,2,3].doubleAll()
```

and

```
a.myEach(...)
```

both work.

EDIT:

The error returned when calling myEach on [1,2,3] rather than on variable a (== [1,2,3]) is

```
[1,2,3].myEach(function (num) {
        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'myEach' of undefined
```

Could someone please explain to this newbie what accounts for this situation?

Comment: what are you expecting output of [1,2,3].myEach(...) and a.myEach(....)

Comment: How does it fail? What error does it give? Please create a demo for us on http://jsfiddle.net/ so that we may reproduce the problem.

Comment: In addition do use the `var` keyword when declaring variables. Otherwise your code may have unexpected problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error you have, but I tried this on node.js and it work well:

```
Array.prototype.doubleAll = function () {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
     output.push(this[i] * 2);
  }
  return output;
};

console.log([1,2,3].doubleAll());

Array.prototype.myEach = function (fun) {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       fun(this[i]);
   }
};

[1,2,3,4,5].myEach(function (num) {
    console.log(num);
});
```

Of course, you don' need "output" var in myEach because you return nothing, you call a function instead. And the second problem, you must add "var" for output else it become a global var and could have unexpected pugs.

Answer (score 0):

output is not declared in the function and a window.output would be created but the code as is works:

```
Array.prototype.myEach = function (fun) {
  var output = [],i;
  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    output.push(fun(this[i]));
  }
  return output;
};

[1,2,3].myEach(function (num) {
  console.log(num);
});
```

Extending native objects [breaks encapsulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes) but if your code will never run with 3rd party libraries then that's not something to worry about too much.